# Как учится читать длинные выражения на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

По типу этого:

```
const wave = s => Array.from( s, (_,i) => /\s/.test(s[i]) ? null : s.slice(0,i) + s[i].toUpperCase() + s.slice(i+1) ).filter(Boolean) ;
```

Меня интересует видя эту строку с чего начинать и как разобрать что делает.

Comment: Нужно учиться *не писать* длинные выражения :)

Comment: При пониманимании механизмов JS читать длинные выражения не очень сложно. Надо просто знать в какой последовательности они выполняются. А вообще длинные выражения это не хорошо.

Comment: Если разобрать это выражение, то получится как-то так https://pastebin.com/DnyYi97S

Answer (score 0):

Методология понимания сводится к школьной программе. Помните, когда в школе учили брать математические операции в скобки для более легко их восприятия? Тут тоже самое. В голове мы делим выражения на логические блоки и учитываем направления выполнения операций. Например операция присвоения выполняетчя с лева на право.

Answer (score 0):

Требуется прокаченный скилл интерпретатора в голове.
Читаем по токену, связываем с построенным окружением, понимаем смысл.
Работает в небольших участках, для крупных минифицированных пакетов есть (должен быть) sourcemap.

Разумеется, несмотря на крутость и лаконичность, всегда есть риск скатится в Perl, так что не увлекайтесь написанием подобного :)